# Time Synchronizer (message_filters) with Custom Message type

Tags: ros, message-filters, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to have one callback function for subscription of two topics. I read online [here](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters?distro=hydro#Time_Synchronizer) that I can use the message_filters library to time synchronize the topics.

In my ROS node when I use the Image and Camera_info topic as suggested in the example code below, I get no errors.

```
  message_filters::Subscriber<Image> image_sub(n, "image", 1);
  message_filters::Subscriber<CameraInfo> info_sub(n, "camera_info", 1);
  TimeSynchronizer<Image, CameraInfo> sync(image_sub, info_sub, 10);
  sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&callback, _1, _2));
```

But when I replace the Image and CameraInfo message formats with custom messages, as shown below, I get a lot of errors. I am attaching the

```
  message_filters::Subscriber<coop_est::FeatureBArray> fea_sub(n, "Feature", 1);
  message_filters::Subscriber<nav_msgs::Odometry> odo_sub(n, "odom", 1);
  message_filters::TimeSynchronizer<coop_est::FeatureBArray, nav_msgs::Odometry> sync(fea_sub, odo_sub, 10);
  sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&FeaturesReceived, _1, _2));
```

**Is message_filters time synchronizer only applicable to certain message formats ?**

The error message I get it very long. I am pasting it here:

```
In file included from /opt/ros/hydro/include/message_filters/time_synchronizer.h:39:0,
                 from /home/quadrotor/catkin_ws/src/coop_est/src/coop_node.cpp:15:
/opt/ros/hydro/include/message_filters/sync_policies/exact_time.h: In member function ‘void message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::add(const typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename message_filters::PolicyBase<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::Events, i>::type&) [with int i = 0, M0 = coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> >, M1 = nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> >, M2 = message_filters::NullType, M3 = message_filters::NullType, M4 = message_filters::NullType, M5 = message_filters::NullType, M6 = message_filters::NullType, M7 = message_filters::NullType, M8 = message_filters::NullType, typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename message_filters::PolicyBase<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::Events, i>::type = ros::MessageEvent<const coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> > >]’:
/opt/ros/hydro/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:358:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::cb(const typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename Policy::Events, i>::type&) [with int i = 0, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> >, nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>, typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename Policy::Events, i>::type = ros::MessageEvent<const coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> > >]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:290:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&, F5&, F6&, F7&, F8&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F5 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F6 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F7 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F8 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> >, nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:282:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&, F5&, F6&, F7&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F5 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F6 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F7 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> >, nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:275:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&, F5&, F6&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F5 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F6 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> >, nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:268:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&, F5&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F5 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> >, nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:261:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> >, nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:254:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> >, nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:247:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> >, nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:240:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> > >, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> >, nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/message_filters/time_synchronizer.h:120:5:   instantiated from ‘message_filters::TimeSynchronizer<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::TimeSynchronizer(F0&, F1&, uint32_t) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> > >, M0 = coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> >, M1 = nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> >, M2 = message_filters::NullType, M3 = message_filters::NullType, M4 = message_filters::NullType, M5 = message_filters::NullType, M6 = message_filters::NullType, M7 = message_filters::NullType, M8 = message_filters::NullType, uint32_t = unsigned int]’
/home/quadrotor/catkin_ws/src/coop_est/src/coop_node.cpp:327:107:   instantiated from here
/opt/ros/hydro/include/message_filters/sync_policies/exact_time.h:127:102: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘ros::message_traits::TimeStamp<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> >, void>’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/message_filters/sync_policies/exact_time.h: In member function ‘void message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::checkTuple(message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::Tuple&) [with M0 = coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> >, M1 = nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> >, M2 = message_filters::NullType, M3 = message_filters::NullType, M4 = message_filters::NullType, M5 = message_filters::NullType, M6 = message_filters::NullType, M7 = message_filters::NullType, M8 = message_filters::NullType, message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::Tuple = boost::tuples::tuple<ros::MessageEvent<const coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> > >, ros::MessageEvent<const nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> > >, ros::MessageEvent<const message_filters::NullType>, ros::MessageEvent<const message_filters::NullType>, ros::MessageEvent<const message_filters::NullType>, ros::MessageEvent<const message_filters::NullType>, ros::MessageEvent<const message_filters::NullType>, ros::MessageEvent<const message_filters::NullType>, ros::MessageEvent<const message_filters::NullType>, boost::tuples::null_type>, typename message_filters::PolicyBase<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::M8Event = ros::MessageEvent<const message_filters::NullType>, typename message_filters::PolicyBase<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::M7Event = ros::MessageEvent<const message_filters::NullType>, typename message_filters::PolicyBase<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::M6Event = ros::MessageEvent<const message_filters::NullType>, typename message_filters::PolicyBase<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::M5Event = ros::MessageEvent<const message_filters::NullType>, typename message_filters::PolicyBase<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::M4Event = ros::MessageEvent<const message_filters::NullType>, typename message_filters::PolicyBase<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::M3Event = ros::MessageEvent<const message_filters::NullType>, typename message_filters::PolicyBase<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::M2Event = ros::MessageEvent<const message_filters::NullType>, typename message_filters::PolicyBase<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::M1Event = ros::MessageEvent<const nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> > >, typename message_filters::PolicyBase<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::M0Event = ros::MessageEvent<const coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> > >]’:
/opt/ros/hydro/include/message_filters/sync_policies/exact_time.h:130:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::add(const typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename message_filters::PolicyBase<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::Events, i>::type&) [with int i = 0, M0 = coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> >, M1 = nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> >, M2 = message_filters::NullType, M3 = message_filters::NullType, M4 = message_filters::NullType, M5 = message_filters::NullType, M6 = message_filters::NullType, M7 = message_filters::NullType, M8 = message_filters::NullType, typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename message_filters::PolicyBase<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::Events, i>::type = ros::MessageEvent<const coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> > >]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:358:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::cb(const typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename Policy::Events, i>::type&) [with int i = 0, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> >, nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>, typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename Policy::Events, i>::type = ros::MessageEvent<const coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> > >]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:290:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&, F5&, F6&, F7&, F8&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F5 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F6 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F7 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F8 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> >, nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:282:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&, F5&, F6&, F7&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F5 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F6 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F7 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> >, nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:275:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&, F5&, F6&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F5 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F6 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> >, nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:268:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&, F5&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F5 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> >, nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:261:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> >, nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:254:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> >, nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:247:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> >, nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:240:5:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> > >, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> >, nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/message_filters/time_synchronizer.h:120:5:   instantiated from ‘message_filters::TimeSynchronizer<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::TimeSynchronizer(F0&, F1&, uint32_t) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> > >, M0 = coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> >, M1 = nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> >, M2 = message_filters::NullType, M3 = message_filters::NullType, M4 = message_filters::NullType, M5 = message_filters::NullType, M6 = message_filters::NullType, M7 = message_filters::NullType, M8 = message_filters::NullType, uint32_t = unsigned int]’
/home/quadrotor/catkin_ws/src/coop_est/src/coop_node.cpp:327:107:   instantiated from here
/opt/ros/hydro/include/message_filters/sync_policies/exact_time.h:181:7: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘ros::message_traits::TimeStamp<coop_est::FeatureBArray_<std::allocator<void> >, void>’
make[2]: *** [coop_est/CMakeFiles/coop_node.dir/src/coop_node.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [coop_est/CMakeFiles/coop_node.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

Thank you for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197811/time-synchronizer-(message_filters)-with-custom-message-type/) by [satk](https://answers.ros.org/users/5181/satk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-11-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) on 2014-11-19**:
TimeSynchronizer should work with any type that has a standard header. Can you post the error message?

**Comment by [satk](https://answers.ros.org/users/5181/satk/) on 2014-11-20**:
Thank you for your reply kmhallen. I have edited the original question to include the error message.

**Comment by [pan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34568/pan/) on 2018-07-12**:
I got the same synchrony problem with my custom message. and My message did has Header. part of error as follow:

```
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:392:35: error: no match for call to ‘(boost::_mfi::mf2<void, subAndPub, const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >&
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This error happens if your custom message does not have a header. Add the line:

```
Header header
```

at the top of you .msg file.

Note that you have to fill `header.stamp` with a time stamp for making the time sychronizer work at runtime.

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [satk](https://answers.ros.org/users/5181/satk/) on 2014-11-20**:
Adding Header header in my .msg file fixed the problem. Thanks!  Also I filled the header.stamp by writing this command `msg.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();` before publishing to the custom message.

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-11-21**:
Plz mark the answer as accepted, if the issue is completely solved....

**Comment by [JKaiser](https://answers.ros.org/users/33362/jkaiser/) on 2018-08-09**:
That didn't solve it for me...My custom message has the Header and I still get that leghty error message from the question. I know my custom message works as using a different callback for it gets it working, but I really need it to sinchronize with another message type